# Relative cell reference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in three columns, A, B and C.
I want to copy the following 3 values from column C if there is a match between column A and B. For example, I would like to copy number 1,3 and 6 from column C because A and B match in third row.

```
A   B   C
1   2   4
3   4   4
5   5   1
4   6   3
4   8   6
1   8   3
```

I have tried Resize, `Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 3)).Copy` etc. but nothing seem to work.

```
Sub test()

Dim rngsize As Range, rngsize2 As Range, rngmake As Range, rngmake2 As Range, rngprice As Range, rngprice2 as range, i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer
x = 3
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 7 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngsize = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & i)
        Set rngsize2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & j)

        Set rngmake = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & i)
        Set rngmake2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & j)

        Set rngprice = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("X" & i)
        Set rngprice2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X" & j)


        If rngsize * 0.5 <= rngsize And rngsize2 + 1.5 >= rngsize Then

            If rngmake2 * 0.5 <= rngmake And rngmake2 * 1.5 >= rngmake Then

                Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 3)).Copy

                rngprice2.Copy

                Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("F" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy


                x = x + 1

            End If
        End If

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont get the idea here. There is a match on the third row, so you take what c column has after the third row without duplicating?

Comment: Right now the code is copying the price in the same row as the size and make, but I want it to copy the following same prices. Hope it makes sense and thanks

Comment: Nothing in your code appears to do anything with either of columns A, B, or C...

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the `Selection` is in this context.

Comment: try `rngprice.resize(,3).copy`

Comment: You should also change `x=x+1` to `x=x+3`

Comment: Have you tried storing the copied values in an array?

Comment: Change this: Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 3)).Copy --To This:-->  Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row+2, 3)).Copy

Comment: or, if you only need numbers in column C, then use this:  Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), Cells(Selection.Row+2, 3)).Copy

Comment: Thank you. I have tried all of the above but nothing seems to work. Just to clarify and I apologize for any misunderstanding. Column A, B and C were meant as an example. The prices I want to copy appear in Sheet2 column X and should only be copied if size and make match.

Comment: Should `If rngsize * 0.5 <= rngsize And rngsize2 + 1.5 >= rngsize Then` be `If rngsize2 * 0.5 <= rngsize And rngsize2 * 1.5 >= rngsize Then`. What is `rngPayroll2`?  Why this complicated way of comparing two numbers?

Comment: You have nested loops so you are comparing every value in column A against every value in column B. Is this what you want.

Comment: You cannot use `Selection.Row` because you are not selecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I could not follow your code so I threw something together based on your example and description.  You will have to modify the constants and worksheets to fit your application.

From your description and example you want VBA for:
When A matches B in the same row, copy C from that row and C from the next 2 rows to another worksheet.

```
Private Sub CopyMatch()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsPaste As Worksheet

Const intACol As Integer = 1
Const intBCol As Integer = 2
Const intCCol As Integer = 3
Const intPasteCol As Integer = 1
Const intCopyRowStart As Integer = 2
Const intPasteRowStart As Integer = 1

'assign worksheets
Set wsCopy = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsPaste = Sheets("Sheet2")

'cycle through each row
i = intCopyRowStart
j = intPasteRowStart
Do Until wsCopy.Cells(i, intACol).Value = "" And _
         wsCopy.Cells(i, intBCol).Value = "" And _
         wsCopy.Cells(i, intCCol).Value = ""
    'check for A-B match
    If wsCopy.Cells(i, intACol).Value = wsCopy.Cells(i, intBCol).Value Then
        'copy C value from match row + 2 next rows for C
        wsCopy.Range(Cells(i, intCCol), Cells(i + 2, intCCol)).Copy
        'paste in other sheet
        wsPaste.Cells(j, intPasteCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        j = j + 3
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

This returned the values 1,3, & 6 in another sheet.

---

My attempt to apply this to your code is as follows:

```
Sub test()

Dim rngsize As Range, rngsize2 As Range, rngmake As Range, rngmake2 As Range, rngprice As Range, rngprice2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer
x = 3
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 7 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngsize = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & i)
        Set rngsize2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & j)
        Set rngmake = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & i)
        Set rngmake2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & j)
        Set rngprice = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("X" & i)
        Set rngprice2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X" & j)

        If rngsize * 0.5 <= rngsize And rngsize2 + 1.5 >= rngsize Then
            If rngmake2 * 0.5 <= rngmake And rngmake2 * 1.5 >= rngmake Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(rngprice.Row, rngprice.Column), Cells(rngprice.Row + 2, rngprice.Column)).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet4").Range("F" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                x = x + 3
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

It runs, not sure if it works as intended though.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code and adjusted accordingly to (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(i, rngprice), Cells(i + 2, rngprice)).Copy)  However I keep getting an error message around the "Cells(i+2...) and Cells(i...)": =< Application-defined or  object defined error"

Comment: In your code, you are setting the ranges to only one cell each.

Comment: hmm, I keep getting a run time error '1004' - app-defined or object defined error even though I use the exact same code?